# Scaffolding feature for winforms or wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, winforms

I'd like to build a new winforms or wpf application, in which I'd like to use the concept of `scaffolding` like I saw for the Asp.net mvc5 application

[Introduction To Scaffolding in Visual Studio 2013 RC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/introduction-of-scaffolding-in-visual-studio-2013-rc/)

I need to know if this feature exists for the desktop applications like winforms or wpf

Comment: Downvoters explain your reasons

Comment: There are some custom (for example on CodeProject) or commercial implementations of the feature you look for, but I don't think Microsoft created one for WPF or Silverlight.

Comment: @schglurps do u think that it is a reason for downvoting

Comment: There is a template when you select MDI Parent Child Application from the Create new Project Window.

Comment: @LamloumiAfif I didn't downvote, I'm the one who voted for your first comment !

Comment: I'm trying to understand this too. Isn't a scaffolder just a fancy word for code generator?  Why couldn't I have certain code templates for certain elements in WPF?  I'm just not seeing why this features is limited to MVC. Sure there's commercial products like CodeSmith, but us poor programmers can't afford such things, and the mechanism for VS to do it is RIGHT THERE... Just not exposed to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to make common code for all application. There are various type of windows application for example Database Application, Client Server Application, System Utilities, etc So, the mechanism of all applications are different then how we can define a common code template for all application. It is up to you that what you want to use Database or TcpIP Socket for your application. I know my answer is not clear. Because it is very hard to define that why we could not create scaffolding.

Comment: I mentionned that I'd like to build a winforms or wpf application !! not any other windows application, see plz my edit